# What is the opposite of "lesser included offence"?

Tags: legal-terms, double-jeopardy

If someone is charged with murder, but acquitted at trial, they can't be later charged with manslaughter, because it's a lesser included offense.

The opposite isn't true, though.

If someone is accused of manslaughter, but acquitted at trial, they can later be charged with murder, because it's a .... what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a "greater offense" -- sometimes also called a "greater included offense."

But you're generally going to be mistaken about whether the defendant can be re-charged after an acquittal on the lesser-included offense. In the United States, at least, the [Double Jeopardy Clause](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/double_jeopardy#:%7E:text=The%20Double%20Jeopardy%20Clause%20in,or%20limb%20.%20.%20.%20.%20%22) would prohibit that prosecutorial strategy. One could still face new charges for the same conduct, but those charges have to pass the [*Blockburger* test](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57019/does-the-u-s-fifth-amendment-prevent-one-from-being-tried-again-for-the-same-cr/57026#57026).